# How to sort columns in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, datatable, datagrid

I have got filled DataTable.

I bind this datatable to DataGridView like as:

```
DataTable dt = serviceSqlite.select(new Pacients());

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

How to sort columns in `dt` before binding? And how to add new column to the fist position in `dt` after getting results from `serviceSqlite.select`?

Comment: Insert a bindingsource as DataSource, based on the DataTable . Now you can sort or filter it..

Comment: @TaW I don't think it's a duplicate of this question. I think the OP wants to reorder the columns. So if you have a Table with two columns like `ID` and `Name` in this order, he wants to reorder them to `Name` - `ID`, wich could be achieved using the `DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex` property. Also I do think the OP creates his columns automatically with the binding. This should be avoided. `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False` and then predefine `columns` and `DataMember` will help for sure.

Comment: Ah, right. Reopened. An alternative to adding a column in the DGV could be to include a computed dummy column in the select.

Comment: Thank you for understanding, The Taw was the most close to my desire to do that

Comment: Do you propose me to use index?